# Keycloak Docker Deployment

Tags: docker, deployment, docker-compose, mariadb, keycloak

I tried to deploy Keycloak and it's database via Docker (Docker-Compose).
It retries 10 times, then failes the deployment. The same docker-compose.yml file worked for me in the past. Haven't done any OS or contianer updates since.
The the following error and warning is thrown:

```
keycloak            | 09:48:42,070 ERROR [org.jgroups.protocols.TCP] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 60) JGRP000034: cff2ce8f5cdf: failure sending message to e832b25e9785: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out
keycloak            | 09:48:45,378 WARN  [org.jgroups.protocols.pbcast.GMS] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 60) cff2ce8f5cdf: JOIN(cff2ce8f5cdf) sent to 05bdb7a4a7f5 timed out (after 3000 ms), on try 0
```

My docker-compose.yml looks like this:

```yaml
keycloak:
    container_name: keycloak
    image: jboss/keycloak:11.0.2
    ports:
      - 8081:8080
    environment:
      - DB_VENDOR=mariadb
      - DB_ADDR=authenticationDB
      - DB_DATABASE=keycloak
      - DB_USER=keycloak
      - DB_PASSWORD=password
      - KEYCLOAK_USER=admin
      - KEYCLOAK_PASSWORD=admin
      - JGROUPS_DISCOVERY_PROTOCOL=JDBC_PING
      - JGROUPS_DISCOVERY_PROPERTIES=datasource_jndi_name=java:jboss/datasources/KeycloakDS,info_writer_sleep_time=500
    depends_on:
      - authenticationDB

  authenticationDB:
    container_name: authenticationDB
    image: mariadb
    volumes:
      - ./keycloakDB:/var/lib/mysql
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
      MYSQL_DATABASE: keycloak
      MYSQL_USER: keycloak
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: password
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "mysqladmin", "ping", "--silent"]
```

I've tried following:

1. SSH into Keycloak's container and curl `authenticationDB:3306`. I've got a `no permission` error so the container could talk to each other.
2. Check if the database is running inside the DB-Container and yes, it's running.

I am running out of ideas.
Normally it retried 10 times, and then successfully deployed keycloak.

Thanks in advance,
Rosario

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say that docker image `jboss/keycloak:11.0.2` doesn't support `JDBC_PING`:

```
$ docker run --rm --entrypoint bash -ti jboss/keycloak:11.0.2 \
  -c 'ls -lah /opt/jboss/tools/cli/jgroups/discovery/'
total 4.0K
drwxrwxr-x. 1 jboss root  25 Sep 15 09:01 .
drwxrwxr-x. 1 jboss root  23 Sep 15 09:01 ..
-rw-rw-r--. 1 jboss root 611 Sep 15 09:01 default.cli
```

vs

```
$  docker run --rm --entrypoint bash -ti jboss/keycloak:12.0.2 \
  -c 'ls -lah /opt/jboss/tools/cli/jgroups/discovery/'
total 8.0K
drwxrwxr-x. 1 jboss root  46 Jan 19 07:27 .
drwxrwxr-x. 1 jboss root  23 Jan 19 07:27 ..
-rw-rw-r--. 1 jboss root 611 Jan 19 07:27 default.cli
-rw-rw-r--. 1 jboss root 605 Jan 19 07:27 JDBC_PING.cli
```

Try to test newer version.